# Regex expression that only uses 3 of 4 criterion

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to do a check on a password supplied to see if it meets a specific criteria from the following:

Password must contain 1 character from 3 of the following:

```
Uppercase letter (A-Z)
Lowercase letter (a-z)
Digit (0-9)
Special character (~`!@#$%^&*()+=_-{}[]\|:;”’?/<>,.)
```

I have no issue creating the regex expression that incorporates all 4 but to create one where only 3 of the 4 are met I am struggling to do, this is what I am using at the moment despite it being incorrect:

```
$("#password").val().match(/^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){1})\S{8,}$/)
```

Comment: If it can be any combination of the three, I think you're stuck with a massive alternation (or multiple regexes, which would be simpler).

Comment: I'll support having 4 separate regex and counting successful matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that.

Instead, check each one individually.

First of all, that makes your code *much* easier for future developers - or even Future You - to understand and update later.

And second, doing them separately allows you to tell the user exactly why you are rejecting their input. You can tell them specifically "hey, you've got upper and lower case letters, which is good, but I'm also going to need either digits or special characters" rather than just "no".

Comment: was writing same answer, easier for everyone and don't forgot to verify this server side too

Comment: Additionally, there are Regex attacks out there that might cause your code to crash or be extremely slow to evaluate. It might be a good idea to use a few simpler regex conditions rather than an overcomplicated one.

Comment: to counter regex atacks, verify password length before using the regex

Comment: To be fair, the worst a "regex attack" could do in this case is crash the user's own browser.